# Qt связь QSlider-а с двумя разными виджетами в одном connect-е с помощью QStackedWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, сигналы-слоты

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть два виджета запушеных в QStackedWidget, если слота называются одинаково можно ли их так законектить:

```
connect(dial, SIGNAL(valueChange(int)), stackedwgt->currentWidget(), SLOT(slot(int)));
```

Я так сделал и на первый виджет все работает, а на второй нет.

Как сделать что бы при смене currentWidget-а все работало?

Comment: Индекс первой страницы Стэка равен 0, второй 1 и так далее. Если ваш слайдер передает именно такие значения, то все должно работать. Только слот там не slot, а setCurrentIndex

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ, я возможно не правильно понял, но  у меня есть два виджета с Одинаковыми слотами (их условно 10 штук) и эти два виджета я вставил в QStackedWidget, что бы они по нажатию кнопки они менялись (и это работает) но для одного эти соединения работают, а для другого нет. Можно ли сделать что бы "Receiver obj" менялся вместе с переключением текущего виджета. Дико извиняюсь, что я такой тупой, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать

Comment: Вы не приводите весь код, поэтому приходится додумывать. Вот что я додумал. connect у Вас только 1, при этом связываете Вы с currentWidget, предполагая, что этот метод выдает текущий виджет на момент прихода сигнала. Это не так.  currentWidget выдает виджет на момент связывания. Для того, чтобы все работало как надо, Вам нужно сделать связывание с каждым виджетом (т.е. если у вас 10 виджетов, то вы должны сделать 10 коннектов). На самом деле это неправильно. Можно поступить по другому. Через лямбду вызывать конкретный слот currentWidget

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предложил такое решение

```
connect(ui->dial, &QDial::valueChanged, [=](int i){
    qobject_cast<CustomWidget*>(stackedwgt->currentWidget())->slot(i);
});
```

`CustomWidget*` - это Ваш родительский класс виджета, от которого должны быть унаследованы все вкладки. И этот класс должен иметь виртуальный метод `slot(int i)`.

Comment: Там структура примерно такая:

`QStackedWidget * stackedWidget = new QStackedWidget(this);
stackedWidget->addWidget(new Class1);
stackedWidget->addWidget(new Class2);

connect(modeSwitchObj, SIGNAL(modeChange(int)), stackedWidget, SLOT((setCurrentIndex(int)));


connect(QSlider какой-то, SIGNAL(valueChange(int)), stackedWidget->currentWidget(), SLOT((какой-то слот));
...
connect(QSlider какой-то, SIGNAL(valueChange(int)), stackedWidget->currentWidget(), SLOT((какой-то слот));



//сигнатура слотов одинаковая у обоих классов`

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, буду разбираться)

Comment: @DenQt Вообще раньше это делалось через QSignalMaper, но сейчас он deprecated, поэтому рекомендую использовать лямбда функции, для того, чтобы срабатывать по ситуации.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое Роман!

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Нужно сделать так:

```
// Например в конструкторе
// CustomWidget это ваш виджет, если у вас их много, то код немного усложнится, но 
// принцип будет тот же
// [&](){} - лямбда-слот
    connect(ui->stackedWidget, &QStackedWidget::currentChanged, [&](int index) {
        CustomWidget* w = dynamic_cast<CustomWidget*>(ui->stackedWidget->currentWidget());
        if( w != nullptr ) {
            // ... это ваши управляющие виджеты с соответствующими сигналами
            connect(..., w, &CustomWidget::slot1, Qt::UniqueConnection);
            connect(..., w, &CustomWidget::slot2, Qt::UniqueConnection);
            // ...
            connect(..., w, &CustomWidget::slotN, Qt::UniqueConnection);
        };
    });
```

Таким образом, вы пересоедините все ваши управляющие виджеты с виджетами в стеке. Флаг [Qt::UniqueConnection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) предотвратит множественные соединения одних и тот же сигналов с теми же слотами, и будет только одно соединение.

Можно добавить отсоединение от предыдущего (уже не активного) виджета через хранение указателя на предыдущий виджет, сути не меняет.

Можно просто в том же конструкторе соединить все ваши управляющие виджеты со стековыми.

Comment: Ваш ответ неправильный. Поскольку каждый раз при изменении currentwidget вы дополнительно делаете связку signal-slot. После долгой работы у вас будет несколько событий на один и тот же сигнал, т.е. срабатывание на изменение слайдера будет происходить многократно  в одном и том же виджете.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, мне явно знаний мат. части не хватает)

Comment: @RomanOzhegov так нормально?

Comment: Лучше, явных ошибок нет. Но есть ошибки поведения. Вы каждый раз вызываете обработчик события смены виджета, хотя это не обязательно, посмотрите на мой ответ, мне кажется он более оптимален по количеству сигнал-слотов. Ну и по лишним действиям.